# Trying to alter usage of React-JSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I've got things working well with React-JSS: https://cssinjs.org/react-jss

The CSS styles are stored in an external file, `styles.js`.  A `classes` object is then instantiated in the top-level component like this:

```
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';
import styleSheet from './styles.js';

class UserMgmtPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
        <UsersProvider>
          <AddUsers classes={classes} />
        </UsersProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styledComponent = injectSheet(styleSheet)(UserMgmtPage);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  session: state.session,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(styledComponent);
```

The "problem" is that `classes` needs to be passed down from component to sub-component to sub-sub-component through prop drilling.  I would like to avoid doing this and instead independently utilize `classes` in each sub-component that needs it - kind of like the way a React Context can be imported into any component, avoiding prop drilling.

I've tried several things but none work.  Might anyone know of an approach that would work to accomplish this?